# Why can't I use malloc to set array size larger than what is needed?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I am coming from Python so using malloc is new to me.  Intuitively the below should work but having syntax issues. In my first line I want to set array size to be a max of 8 ints. In the second line, I want to add those 4 ints. This line is for example only, in production I will have user input up to an 8-digit number. When I go to compile (clang) I get `size of array has non-integer type 'void *'`  If I comment out this first line and initialize with the second line (and adding int type) the code works. So I am obviously setting the size incorrectly. Any ideas?

```
int main(void)

{

    int mult_digits[malloc(8 * sizeof(int))];
    mult_digits[] = {1,2,3,4};
    int size_mult = sizeof mult_digits / sizeof *mult_digits;
    printf("Size of the array is %d\n", size_mult);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int mult_digits[malloc(8 * sizeof(int))];`, that's not how you allocate memory with `malloc`. [Refer here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) for examples.

Comment: Thanks @jeffrey. I initially had 'int *mult_digits = malloc(8 * sizeof(int));' but was getting "error: expected expression" when trying to add 4 ints to the array with the second line.  Going one at a time as in 'mult-digits[0] = 1;' works but not several at once.  Guess that should have been my main question.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Just trying to ask a question...sheesh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code is all wrong. You call `malloc` to allocate memory, and `malloc` returns a pointer. Rather than deconstructing your syntax, which is very broken, I'll give a couple of variants of your program.

```
int main(void)
{
    int mult_digits[] = {1,2,3,4};
    int size_mult = sizeof mult_digits / sizeof *mult_digits;
    printf("Size of the array is %d\n", size_mult);
    return 0;
}
```

Here the array is not allocated dynamically. It's a local variable with automatic, stored on the stack.

For dynamic allocation you would do this:

```
int main(void)
{
    int *mult_digits = malloc(4*sizeof *mult_digits);
    mult_digits[0] = 1;
    mult_digits[1] = 2;
    mult_digits[2] = 3;
    mult_digits[3] = 4;
    free(mult_digits);
    return 0;
}
```

The argument to `malloc` is the number of bytes to be returned. The value returned is the address of the new block of memory. Note also here that we made a call to `free` to deallocate the memory. If you omit that, the memory will be leaked.

With this variant, there is no way to recover the length of the array from `mult_digits`. I know that might freak you out, coming from Python, but I repeat. There is no way to recover the length of the array from `mult_digits`. It's your job to keep track of that information.

Now, you wanted to over-allocate the memory. You can certainly do that:

```
int main(void)
{
    int *mult_digits = malloc(8*sizeof *mult_digits);
    mult_digits[0] = 1;
    mult_digits[1] = 2;
    mult_digits[2] = 3;
    mult_digits[3] = 4;
    free(mult_digits);
    return 0;
}
```

Here we only used the first 4 elements, and ignored the final 4. That's just fine. In case you do over-allocate you would typically need to keep track of both the allocated length, and the in-use length. You can then add new items by increasing the in-use length, up until you reach the allocated length. The you need to reallocate a larger block. I guess that's what you are driving at.

Comment: thanks for comment about recovering length.  Guess that's a pretty key point given what I'm trying to do.  Sizeof trick wont work here I guess.

Comment: When you use `malloc` to allocate memory, all you have is a pointer. You have no way at all of retrieving information about the size of block the pointer refers to. C is just really hard work!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your syntax. What you meant was: `int *mult_digits = malloc(8 * sizeof(int));`

After that, `mult_digits[] = {1,2,3,4};` is wrong. You could, however,

```
mult_digits[0] = 1;
mult_digits[1] = 2;
mult_digits[2] = 3;
mult_digits[3] = 4;
```

But unless you have some reason to swim into the pointer deep end, you might just want to:

```
int mult_digits[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

---

Edit: to help with applying this answer, here is a full modified function that compiles and runs:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int mult_digits[] = {1,2,3,4};
    int size_mult = sizeof mult_digits / sizeof *mult_digits;
    printf("Size of the array is %d\n", size_mult);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is what I did the first time. However clang is giving me "error: expected expression" when I use 'mult_digits[] = {1,2,3,4}' and if I use 'int mult_digits[] = {1,2,3,4}' I get an error about changing the type since I initialied as int* previously.

Comment: @Andy check your code then, you're doing something wrong. In your comment, you said _when I use 'multi_digits[]..._   but you left out `int` in your comment. It needs to be on the code line; I verified using clang and it works fine. `int *z = {1, 2, ...};` will not work.

Answer (score 1):

in square brackets you must specify the number of elements needed, not the length in byte of the array. you can use malloc to do

```
int* multdigits = malloc(sizeof(int)*8);
mult_digits[0] = 1;
```

etc

(sorry if my syntax is wrong, i don't write c code from years!)

they're two ways to do the same thing. see "malloc" as the "new" operator.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
int main(void)
{
    int mult_digits[] = {1,2,3,4};
    int size_mult = sizeof mult_digits / sizeof int;
    printf("Size of the array is %d\n", size_mult);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @r sahu yes that works (I mentioned this in my original comment). However this doesnt work when I first initialize size of the array to 8 ints.